# Existente of a point in Domain for given value on integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Given $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ continuous and positive such that $\int _{0}^{1}f(x) dx = 3$ then there exists only one $c \in [0,1]$ such that $\int _{0}^{c}f(x) dx =2 $

I was thinking of a way to use the intermediate value theorem to prove It, but i don't think It Will work, i think this is a Very simple question but i'm struggling to solve It, any hints?

Comment: Work on $g(x) = \int_0^x f(t) dt$.

Comment: @nicomezi can i assure It is continuous?

Comment: You can even prove that it is differentiable.

Comment: @ArcticChar true

Comment: Continuity of $f$ is not needed. It is sufficient to assume that $f$ is positive on whole $[0,1]$ and Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$F(y) =  \int\limits_{0}^{y} f(x)dx$ is a continuous, monotonically increasing function with $F(0) = 0$ and $F(1) = 3$. Thus, there is a value $c$ for which $F(c) = 2$ given $0 < 2 < 3$i

N.B. I assume a positive function is the function with its values strictly greater than zero.

Comment: The question asks to prove that there is "only one" value. So in fact I think the statement is not true.

Comment: As f(x) is positive, F(x) is monotonically increasing, which guarantees uniqueness.

Comment: See the counter-example in my answer. @vladz

Comment: In your example f(x) is not positive ( = 0)

Comment: Well, both definitions exist for a positive function ($f \ge 0$ and $f>0$). So technically we are both right.

Comment: Positive means greater than zero, what you are referring to is non-negative

Comment: I linked a wikipedia page where positive means explicitely $f \ge 0$. Furthermore, on the derivative page, again on wikipedia, says that a differentiable function is increasing iff the derivative is positive. A constant function is increasing, yet its derivative is $0$. So a positive function may refer to a large or a strict inequality, depending on the context. As Paramanand Singh said, the definition you use may be more common, but both exist.

Comment: Fair enough. I will modify my answer to state in which sense I mean the function to be positive

Answer (score 3):

If you only ask for positiveness ( defined here as $f \ge 0$ ), it is not true. The existence of such $c$ is assured by vladz's answer but it fails to always be unique.

Consider :

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
4(\frac 1 2 -x) & \text{ on } [0, \frac 1 2], \\
0 & \text{ on } [\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4],\\
(x- \frac 3 4)8 & \text{ on } [\frac 3 4,1].
\end{cases}$$

It satisfies all your conditions, but
$\int_0^c f(x) =2$ for every $c \in [\frac 1 2, \frac 3 4]$.

If you suppose $f >0$, then $g(x) = \int_0^x f (t) dt$ is strictly increasing, preventing the previous case to happen.

Comment: According to this wikipedia page, $f$ positive means $f \ge 0$ : https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Positive_Real_Function @ParamanandSingh

Comment: What you call positive is also known as non-negative. Wiki page mentions this too. The issues of terminology are best handled by explicitly mentioning the meanings of the ambiguous terms being used.

Comment: Well there is no ambiguity here about what I call a positive function since my example contains a whole interval where the function is $0$. And even more with my remark at the end of the answer. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: Also the usage of "positive" as "greater than $0$" is more common as in "let $\epsilon $ be a positive real number". I wonder what prompted wiki to make the word "positive" ambiguous.

Comment: Well, you may be right about what is more common. But I think the answer I wrote is not ambiguous as it is. And we do not know which sense the OP has in mind actually. I will add a slight precision at the beginning though. @ParamanandSingh

Comment: my point was not to point out any mistake, but rather to confirm the terminology you used. +1